# Can we print used test data in html report generaring when using Protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin

Tags: protractor, automated-tests, cucumber, e2e-testing, cucumberjs

I am using protractor cucumber framework for automation testing. 
I am using Protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin to generate reports. 
Can we used print test data in reports? 
Or
Atleast, can we print test data for failure test cases in report where error message is showing?

Comment: Are you framework is included with World?

Comment: Hii.. No my framework is not included with World..

Comment: This can be doable using hooks and World concept in cucumber framework. Refer below pages to get more information on it: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/world.md, https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/hooks.md

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Push your test data into Buffer, which is a node js concept and attach it to this.world like below in hooks file

```
   After(async function () {
    const userDetails = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(Shared.userDetails));
    await this.World.attach(userDetails, 'application/json');
    const testData = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(Shared.testDataObj));
    await this.World.attach(testData, 'application/json');
});
```

At the end cucumber will fetch entire data from this.world and store in cucumber-json-report.json, which we use to generate report with the help of cucumber-html-reporter.